# File Upload interruption

Tags: android

Currently i have an application where an activity calls a service which sends a file to a server. This is working fine..However, i was wondering does anybody know what happens if the internet connection is interrupted. Will the service run again when the connection comes back...Or is there something i need to implement to do this? If so how and what etc? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service will not run again when the connection comes back unless you add logic to do so. I'd recommend using a success flag to determine if a file was uploaded correctly, and if it wasn't due to an error (such as an interrupt), then you start the upload over again.

Perhaps alerting the user that a file upload has failed would be the best route to take, that way he/she can decide if its worth another try. This would also help keep your app from spiraling out of control while endlessly uploading a file to a server (although you could add a variable like maxNumberOfTries to avoid this).

Comment: Could you show me what this logic is i need to implement.thanks

Comment: Hmmm so would this go on the onDestroy function

Comment: I was thinking if in the on destroy function before I destroy, if I run a function to check weather the folder with the files is empty then to destroy else call the service again..would this work?

Comment: I think that would work, although you might want to alert the user that the file wasn't uploaded correctly to begin with. Then they could retry the file upload and know its status. If you want to do it before onDestroy anyways, I would ask the user if they want to keep trying, because that logic will hold up destroying your app. This might anger some users if their phone needs to free up resources and your app is still running strong.